# Regex : must end with the first match of exaclty 10 digits between dashes

Tags: regex

```
2017-34-5-1503650477-547-1234567890-coco.jpg
```

I want to match **2017-34-5-1503650477-**

```
2017-34-5-1503650477-toast.jpg
```

I want to match **2017-34-5-1503650477-**

```
2017-240-1503650477-toast.jpg
```

I want to match **2017-240-1503650477-**

I'm trying to use `/\b^(.*)\-\d{10}\-\b/` but on the first example it matches **2017-34-5-1503650477-547-1234567890-** wheras I want to stop here : **2017-34-5-1503660477-**

Comment: Have you tried  `\d+\-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the laziness modifier:

> Note the question mark in  (.*?)

```
\b^(.*?)\-\d{10}\-\b
```

Here is a regex101 example:
https://regex101.com/r/nQfsE9/1

Comment: I think you mean the laziness modifier? * is by default greedy and you made it not greedy.

Comment: @Alectrona you are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct (the V icon on the left) if thats the case :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Stackoverflow says I need to wait 30 sec :)

Comment: @Alectrona yes, there are limits :) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

`^(\d{1,9}-)+\d{10}`

Where:

- `(\d{1,9}-)+` pairs of 1-9 digits and `-`
- `\d{10}` followed by 10 digits

[example](https://regex101.com/r/lNycdO/1)

Comment: Works fine aswell, and for "2017-34-1503660477---1234567890-5.jpg" it matches only '2017-34-1503660477-' so its nice, thanks